# Parsing a .properties file with getClassLoader()

Tags: java, inputstream, properties-file

I'm writing a Java program that takes a `foo.properties` file and parses it into a `Properties` object. After a quick search, I found this code:

```
public Properties getProperties() throws IOException{
    String fileIn = "foo.properties";
    Properties p = new Properties();
    InputStream inStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileIn);

    if(inStream != null) {
        p.load(inStream);
    } else throw new FileNotFoundException();

    return p;
}
```

My question concerns line 4: why does the code above use `InputStream inStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileIn)`, instead of simply using, say, `FileinputStream fInStream = new FileInputStream(fileIn)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getResourceAsStream() can load files from the classpath rather than an absolute location. Refer to [this excellent article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077352/java-se/smartly-load-your-properties.html.)

Comment: Thank you for this, the article is very exhaustive and clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can load .properties file even if your program is inside JAR repo